# Why were Joab killing all males in Edom?

Tags: army-military-war

http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%2011&version=NKJV?

> 14 Now the Lord raised up an adversary against Solomon, Hadad the
>   Edomite; he was a descendant of the king in Edom. 15 For it happened,
>   when David was in Edom, and Joab the commander of the army had gone up
>   to bury the slain, after he had killed every male in Edom 16 (because
>   for six months Joab remained there with all Israel, until he had cut
>   down every male in Edom), 17 that Hadad fled to go to Egypt, he and
>   certain Edomites of his father’s servants with him. Hadad was still a
>   little child. 18 Then they arose from Midian and came to Paran; and
>   they took men with them from Paran and came to Egypt, to Pharaoh king
>   of Egypt, who gave him a house, apportioned food for him, and gave him
>   land. 19 And Hadad found great favor in the sight of Pharaoh, so that
>   he gave him as wife the sister of his own wife, that is, the sister of
>   Queen Tahpenes. 20 Then the sister of Tahpenes bore him Genubath his
>   son, whom Tahpenes weaned in Pharaoh’s house. And Genubath was in
>   Pharaoh’s household among the sons of Pharaoh.

http://books.google.co.id/books?id=PT1qp_FGYJ0C&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=tikkune+soferim&source=bl&ots=ZyHwvSR-6F&sig=jmfgKFm9ye2HTuUaIfrar4sj9J0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F1bHUqjlHMnprAfOyYGoCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=tikkune%20soferim&f=false

argues that this is due to different possible spelling in Deuteronomy. Not sure what. The Deuteronomy talks about erasing memory of Amalek rather than Edomites. Yoab think that it means killing all the males. Yoab then kill the rabbi that taught him incorrectly.

Comment: What is the question?  You've quoted a passage and given a link that you say argues that "this" is due to spelling differences -- but what is the "this"?  Please make sure that all of the information needed to understand your question is *in* the question; we should not have to follow links to understand what you're asking.  Thank you.

Comment: indeed, I cannot even read the link. exceeded allowed pages for this book error

Answer (score 3):

The word in Devarim is זכר, which depending on the vowel points could either be zeicher, meaning the memory of, or Zechar, the males of.

According to a Midrash, yoav's teacher taught him with the incorrect vocalization, and so he killed only all the males.

Edomite and Amalekite are presumed identical, since Amalek was the grandchild of Edom.

Comment: I always wondered, did he actually teach him the wrong nekudot, or was he doresh incorrectly, something like "al tikre zeicher, ela zechar"?

Comment: I thought torah says to be "nice" to the edomites because they are Israel's brother. So Joab is wrong for not killing everybody and only the male?

Comment: @Menachem I understood it to mean the former. Do you have the original text of the Midrash handy?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I might, if I knew which Midrash it was :)

Comment: in bava batra 21a-b. it seems to be an early childhood rebbe. http://halakhah.com/bababathra/bababathra_21.html

Comment: @joshwaxman, note that in the soncino translation the teacher was negligent in not correcting Yoav, as opposed to teaching it wrong.

Comment: @Menachem Either way, it's the wrong nekudot not a bad drasha. Does seem to indicate that there was no written system of nekudot, or at least there were no dotted texts lying around.

Comment: @joshwaxman - The last Tosafos in Bava Basra 21a is the source for the Soncino comment that Menachem mentioned. And the Marhasha there explains that the reason why Yoav killed only the males of Edom was because he reasoned that if Hashem commanded us to kill only the males of Amalek in a Milchemes Mitzvah (a required war), certainly no more is required for a Milchemes Reshus (an optional war) such as that with Edom.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Yes, although it makes more sense to say the child made a mistake and the teacher didn't correct him (perhaps the teacher held like Rava's position), than to say that the teacher taught it wrong (which is why I thought it might have been a Drush).